# How do I specify column to to select from result of join

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table Ce_Data has a column "Fut_ID"

Why do I get an "ambiguous" error on first line? TX."Fut_ID" does not work either

```
SELECT "Fut_ID"
FROM (
SELECT *
  FROM "Ce_Data" AS M
  JOIN (SELECT "Fut_ID", MAX("Date") AS "Most_Recent"
          FROM "Ce_Data"
         GROUP BY "Fut_ID"
       ) AS R
    ON R."Fut_ID" = M."Fut_ID" AND R."Most_Recent" = M."Date"
) AS TX
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message you receive. The details may not mean anything to you, but they could be useful to someone helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer query picks `Fut_ID` from the inner subquery. However there are *two different* sources to choose `Fut_ID` from: table `Ce_Data` (alias `M`) **and** the derived table with alias `R`. You can work around the problem by using an alias for the field within the derived table:

```
SELECT "Fut_ID"
FROM (
SELECT *
  FROM "Ce_Data" AS M
  JOIN (SELECT "Fut_ID" AS "Fut_ID2", MAX("Date") AS "Most_Recent"
          FROM "Ce_Data"
         GROUP BY "Fut_ID"
       ) AS R
    ON R."Fut_ID2" = M."Fut_ID" AND R."Most_Recent" = M."Date"
) AS TX
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an ambiguous error because `Fut_ID` is in both tables, so it is ambiguous in the subquery (the `*` gets *all* column names, even duplicates).  Just list the columns from the second table explicitly:

```
SELECT TX.*
FROM (SELECT M.*
      FROM "Ce_Data" M JOIN
           (SELECT "Fut_ID", MAX("Date") AS "Most_Recent"
            FROM "Ce_Data"
            GROUP BY "Fut_ID"
           ) R
           ON R."Fut_ID" = M."Fut_ID" AND R."Most_Recent" = M."Date"
     ) TX;
```

(I added the `TX.*` because otherwise the query processing doesn't make sense.)

Or, better yet, use window functions:

```
SELECT TX.*
FROM (SELECT M.*, MAX("Date") OVER (PARTITION BY "Fut_ID") as "Most_Recent"
      FROM "Ce_Data" M 
     ) M
ON "Most_Recent" = "Date"
```